# About Abel Summation

Tags: prime-numbers, euler-mascheroni-constant

http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0504289v3.pdf

Here i'm trying to understand page 5. Writer uses the abel sum to find the sum of the prime's reciprocals. So he founds the formula (2.2.1) Now here y=2 x=x...So where is the -A(y).f(y) ? Doesnt -1/2 is missing? Did i miss something? Please help!